# Boost.Spirit, Nabialek trick and error handling

Tags: c++, error-handling, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Is it possible to combine "generic" error handling (like it's given in the tutorial) with Nabialek trick somehow? Like this:

```
...
on_error<fail>
(
    start
  , std::cout
        << val("Error! Expecting ")
        << _4                               // what failed?
        << val(" here: \"")
        << construct<std::string>(_3, _2)   // iterators to error-pos, end
        << val("\"")
        << std::endl
);

start = *(keyword[_a = _1] > lazy(*_a));

some_other_rule.name("other rule's name");
...
```

Now, when `some_other_rule` is lazy-called and fails, the error message says that `"lazy"` was expected verbatim, and not `"other rule's name"` (which I need). Is it supposed to work that way and I'm simply mistaken somewhere else, or there are some other specific tricks involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've worked it out (post it here for someone who hits the issue):

`some_other_rule` and other rules whose pointers are selected via the `keyword` parser should start with `qi::eps > ...`.

That is because `lazy` is a parser itself, and when the invoked parser fails, `lazy` gets rolled back to try other possible branches. And since the only expectation is the one preceeding it (`... > lazy()`), expectation failure is raised against `lazy`. So, what we do is add another expectation closer to the actual error.